# Storing bytearray strings in-memory

Tags: python, arrays

We have a large number of Python bytearray strings of variable length which need to remain in memory.  Wrt raw-performance, is a Python dictionary the most efficient in-memory storage for read-only random-access for the bytearray strings? The dictionary keys could be integers or strings. If not, what is better?

Comment: For what kind of access? Sequential?

Comment: Use the data structure that is suited to the kind of access you need (e.g. dicts for mapping of unordered keys to values). Asking for "most efficient" doesn't make sense unless you describe what operations you need.

Comment: I don't doubt you would get faster access in terms of raw speed from an in-memory dict, as it is sitting right there in the process. Redis has the benefit/overhead of giving you shared access as a service (over a socket), with replication and locking. It is like comparing a sharpened stick to a swiss army knife

Comment: @jdi question modified to say random-access.

Comment: I think Keith's answer still stands true. If you are just looking for pure access speed, then the python built-in data structures are going to be fastest. What do you need from this data structure besides raw speed? Nothing? Then go with Keith's answer.

Comment: @dbv, I don't understand how an in-memory Python dict is only "marginally" faster than Redis. Python will only have to execute a few hundred CPU instructions to do a dict[key] access, whereas with Redis it'll have to do a few thousand, possibly tens or hundreds of thousands, because it has to [send TCP packets](http://redis.io/topics/protocol) across a socket. Can you post your timings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on how you intend to access them.  If you just want to iterate through them, put them in a `list`.  If you want to search for one by a key, use a `dict`.  No matter what you use, you've already paid for the space for all of your `bytearray`s, the difference between `list`, `dict`, or something else will probably be minimal.  A list will use something like 500,000 references at 4 bytes a piece = 2MB, a `dict` maybe a few times that.

Comment: question modified to say that access is random.

Comment: Random by what?  If your `bytearray`s are numbered from 1 to N and accessed by number, then use a `list`.  If they have string names (or some other opaque token), use a `dict`.  Or is it something else?

Comment: to exapnd on what @KeithRandall just said: dict key:value access is _amortized_ O(1), which means that for very large collections it's actually not O(1) for individual key accesses, but averages to it over many access ops. If you can access the bytearray in a list, using an index (without any additional lookups to determine the correct index position), then that would be the faster than a dict, and absolutely faster than Redis.

Comment: And to further add to @Nisan.H, basically you would need to describe your actual data structure needs for a concrete answer. Otherwise these are just options.

Comment: Thanks for the input. A dict is usually my first choice but wanted to double-check in this case using bytearray strings where speed is important.